# How to get my partition back

Tags: hardware, files

I m a beginner to elementary  and while installing it I chose to install it on my e drive .Now I m not getting any of the partition that I had on my windows like d or c drive nor i can see the files that were in it . When in terminal I type the name of drive (like dev/sda1), it shows no such directory found . Please help me as those were some important files.

Answer (score 1):

Your old partitions should show up in the *Files* file manager under *Devices*. You can click on them to mount them and access the files on these partitions.